# Meteor Restivus Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm using restivus lib but it doesn't work:

this is the simple code:

```js
//first function:
request({
            uri: "http://localhost/my-api/publisher/",
            method: "GET"
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            console.log("Risposta :"+response);
            console.log("Risposta :"+body);
        });

//second function:
 var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
            var Api = new Restivus({
                apiPath: 'my-api/',
                useDefaultAuth: false,
                prettyJson: true
  });

  Api.addRoute('publisher', {authRequired: true},  {
                get: function () {
                    console.log("publisher");
                    return "publisher";
                }

  });


});

server.listen(80, function() {
     console.log((new Date()) + ' Server attivo sulla porta 80');
});
```

log doesn't release any error or other, simply doesn't  return anything.

Some advice?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try from the browser?

Comment: OK, I found error, was http server.